# Balancing the area of curves - integration

Tags: calculus, integration

A linear equation needs to be found $y=ax+b$ with a slope of a maximum value of $10$ degrees that will balance out the area above the line and below the line for the function $\frac{10000}{x+100}+10\cos{\frac{x}{50}}+50-\frac{x}{100}$ between $0<x<1000$.

I am quite confused as to where to progress from here, I presume I need to find the integral of the function and then minus $y=ax+b$??? Any help will be 100% appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution.

Find the average value of your function from $0$ to $1000$: let's call it $b$. Then an equation that splits the area in half is

$$y=0x+b$$

This slope is zero, which is certainly less than $10$ degress.

Remember, the average of the function $f(x)$ for $a\le x\le b$ is

$$Avg=\frac{\int_a^b f(x)\,dx}{b-a}$$

The fact that you want $0<x<1000$ rather than $0\le x\le 1000$ is irrelevant here.